# How can I start installed browser without adding IE driver or Chrome driver in selenium web driver?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I have installed IE and chrome browser in my computer. I want to run my selenium script from original browser with all add-ons and default setting.

I am able to find *.exe of browser with some capabilities.But can not able to write and open link (driver.get()) in browser. Please refer following code.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL, DriverTestNG.url);
DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer().setCapability("ignoreProtectedModeSettings", true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "src/main/resources/Framework/Drivers/Windows/IEDriverServer_Win32_2.40.0/IEDriverServer.exe");
cap.setCapability("IE.binary", "C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe");
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
cap.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
cap.setCapability("enablePersistentHover", false);
cap.setCapability("elementScrollBehavior", 1);
cap.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", true);
cap.setCapability("nativeEvents", true);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
```

May be I have missed something.I am not sure about this that selenium web driver supports this functionality or not.

Please guide me for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding to your title, you can not run Internet Explorer or Chrome without using a `webDriver` because you need the `webDriver` as an API to access the functionality of IE or chrome.

But you can still use extensions and your default settings. The reason why you don't see any extensions running `chromeDriver` is that it always creates a new temporary profile for each test-session. If you want to run your own custom profile with extensions and settings you have to tell chromeDriver which user profile it should use by defining the `user-data-dir`.

You can find the capabilities here:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

example:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data");
```

You can also specifiy extensions by using:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/extensions

I don't use `IEdriver` so I can't tell you how it works with the IE but as far as i know the internet explorer does not have profiles and the extensions are managed somewhere in the registry. So I would assume that extensions installed before running the tests are available also trough `IEWebDriver`.